# Moving older versions of a specific file from one folder to another in visual basic

Tags: vb.net

I am completely new to Visual Basic and am waiting for some books to show up in the mail, but until then I was hoping to do some research on how to move older versions of a file from one folder to another. In one folder we have a bunch of AutoCAD drawings of parts that get cut out on our CNC Router. Example = 480-094-120-A. But when a revision is made to the part, our software produces another .dwg file 480-094-120-B. I am wanting to write a program that a couple of times a week I could run it and have it take the older revision and move it to a different folder. Any pointers or advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You'll want to look at the filenames and figure out how to identify which ones are different versions of the same thing. And have a look at what happens after a -Z suffix - does it go AA, AB, AC... or AA, BB, CC... ? .NET classes which would be of particular interest to you would be the [Directory Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and the [Path Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), both of which have examples in their documentation. Come back to us and show relevant code if you get any problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I researched extensively and plugged away at it all weekend and was able to write the program without any dialog boxes. Here is what I ended up with and it works like a dream:

`Option Strict On
Option Explicit On
Imports System
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub StartButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles StartButton.Click
    Dim Files() As String = IO.Directory.GetFiles("W:\Router\DWG Files", "*.dwg*").ToArray
    Dim Files2 As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)

    ListBox1.Items.Clear()
    For Each File As String In Files
        ListBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(File))
    Next

    Array.Sort(Files)

    Dim iA As Integer

    For iA = 0 To Files.Length - 2
        Dim iB As Integer = iA + 1
        Dim filename1 As String = CStr((ListBox1.Items(iA)))
        Dim filename2 As String = CStr((ListBox1.Items(iB)))
        Dim eval1 As String = filename1.Substring(0, 11)
        Dim eval3 As String = filename1.Substring(12)
        Dim eval2 As String = filename2.Substring(0, 11)
        Dim eval4 As String = filename2.Substring(12)

        If eval1 = eval2 And eval3 < eval4 Then
            Files2.Add(Path.GetFileName(filename1))
            ListBox2.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(filename1))
        End If

    Next iA

    Dim sourcePath As String = "W:\Router\DWG Files"
    Dim destinationPath As String = "W:\Router\Old Revisions"

    For Each File As String In Files2
        System.IO.File.Move(Path.Combine(sourcePath, File), (Path.Combine(destinationPath, File)))
    Next

    MessageBox.Show("Old Revision Archiving Complete!")

End Sub

Private Sub CloseButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CloseButton.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

End Class`

I appreciate the help and will use the code supplied above for future reference. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to work out what exactly the naming convention is as Andrew mentioned above. Once you have that the rest is fairly straight forward. The following code will get you started...

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

#Region "Buttons"
    Private Sub ButtonSource_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonSource.Click
        Dim browseDialog As FolderBrowserDialog = New FolderBrowserDialog
        If TextBoxSourcePath.Text > "" AndAlso IO.Directory.Exists(TextBoxSourcePath.Text) Then
            browseDialog.SelectedPath = TextBoxSourcePath.Text
        End If
        If browseDialog.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            TextBoxSourcePath.Text = browseDialog.SelectedPath
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub ButtonDestination_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonDestination.Click
        Dim browseDialog As FolderBrowserDialog = New FolderBrowserDialog
        If TextBoxDestinationPath.Text > "" AndAlso IO.Directory.Exists(TextBoxDestinationPath.Text) Then
            browseDialog.SelectedPath = TextBoxDestinationPath.Text
        End If
        If browseDialog.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            TextBoxDestinationPath.Text = browseDialog.SelectedPath
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub ButtonProcess_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonProcess.Click
        If Not TextBoxDestinationPath.Text = String.Empty AndAlso Not TextBoxSourcePath.Text Is String.Empty Then
            If IO.Directory.Exists(TextBoxSourcePath.Text) Then
                'fetch list of files
                Dim filesToCopy As List(Of FileInfo) = fetchFileList(TextBoxSourcePath.Text)
                'now process the full list of all the files in the directory, narrowing to only the files we want to back up...
                filesToCopy = filterFileList(filesToCopy)
                'copy the files to our backup location
                If Not filesToCopy Is Nothing Then
                    copyFiles(filesToCopy, TextBoxDestinationPath.Text)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
#End Region

#Region "Process Files"
    Private Function fetchFileList(ByVal directory As String) As List(Of FileInfo)
        Try
            Dim fileList As New List(Of FileInfo)
            Dim folderInfo As New DirectoryInfo(directory)
            Dim fileArray As FileInfo() = folderInfo.GetFiles()
            For Each fileInformation As FileInfo In fileArray
                fileList.Add(fileInformation)
            Next
            Return fileList
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return Nothing
        End Try
    End Function
    Private Sub copyFiles(ByVal filesToCopy As List(Of FileInfo), ByVal destinationDirectory As String)
        If Not filesToCopy Is Nothing AndAlso filesToCopy.Count > 0 Then
            'loop through each of the source files and back them up
            For Each currentFile In filesToCopy
                'create the new path out of the current file name and the destination path
                Dim currentFileBackupPath = Path.Combine(destinationDirectory, currentFile.Name)
                Try
                    'now copy the file to our backup location
                    File.Copy(currentFile.FullName, currentFileBackupPath, True)
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MsgBox(String.Format("Error occured copying: {0}{1}{2}", currentFile.Name, Environment.NewLine, ex.Message))
                End Try
            Next
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Function filterFileList(ByVal filesToCopy As List(Of FileInfo)) As List(Of FileInfo)
        Dim filteredListOfFiles As New List(Of FileInfo)

        'do refining logic here ... using LINQ maybe....?

        Return filteredListOfFiles
    End Function
#End Region


End Class
```